# Rails 3.1: Access a fingerprinted image from css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, stylesheet, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Is there an elegant way to access images with fingerprints in production from css?

I know I can use erb for css, but adding urls with erb looks ugly, and I think it should be someway automated. Besides I don't want to change vendor stylesheets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think **image-url** should solve this problem

```
.btn_back:hover {background-image: image-url('btn_back_push.png');}
```

it works for me in dev. mode as well as in the production with precompiled assets as result

dev. mode:

```
.btn_nav:hover {
  background-image: url("btn_nav_push.png");
}
```

production:

```
.btn_nav:hover{background-image:url(/assets/btn_nav_push-094b577d7e9e1cc6d5aced334f3fe8b3.png)}.
```

Answer (score 3):

sass-rails has added a helper for this called image-path.  You can use it like this:

#image {
  background: image-path("rails.png")
}

This won't work for normal css files, but because scss is a superset of css, so you should be able to change the extension to .scss and all will be good.

Comment: The README for sass-rails has more info on these new helpers.  https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

Comment: Thanks, that's great. It solves the half of my problems. Still not sure what to do with vendor styles and js files.

Comment: This did work for me, but only if I used relative paths, not absolute ones.  (And remembering to leave out the `/assets` in either case.)  For vendored images (such as bootstrap glyphicons), I use `public/img`